# How to create a database design for keeping records for specific equipment with specific tasks?

Tags: mysql

**Goal:**

My main goal is to create a C# Windows Form application to do the following:

- Add / Edit / Remove Equipment Names. This will interact with MySQL table.

Here is the schema:

```
-- Maintenance equipment create table
CREATE TABLE Maintenance_Equipment (
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(140),
serial_number varchar(20));

-- Insert some values to Maintenance equipment
insert into maintenance_equipment 
(name, serial_number)
values
('Equipment 1', '1555');
```

**Status: Done**

- Add/ Edit / Remove Tasks. Also will interact with MySQL table

Tasks Scema:

```
-- Tasks
create table tasks(
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
task_name varchar(140));

-- Insert some tasks
insert into tasks(task_name) values ("Buttons/Switched Integrity Check");
```

**Status: Done**

**Here is the bit I am stuck at**

I need to now create a Maintenance Schedule for selected equipment and assign them tasks and to be completed for specific months.

Here is what I drafted up:

```
-- Planner
create table planner (
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
Maintenance_Equipment_ID int,
tasks_ID int,
January bool,
February bool,
March bool,
April bool,
May bool,
June bool,
July bool,
August bool,
September bool,
October bool,
November bool,
December bool);
```

**Details:**

I have created this table like that because, I have the `Maintenance_Equipment_ID` which will be referenced to the `Maintenance_Equipment` table and same for the `Tasks`.

Next, I have every month in each column as `bool` data type. This is because, it represents the frequency of the task for that equipment. Here is an example of inserted values into table `planner`:

```
insert into planner (Maintenance_Equipment_ID, tasks_ID, June, December) values (1, 1, true, true);
```

This shows that `Equipment 1` has a task of `Buttons/Switched Integrity Check` to be checked in `June` & `December`.

**Status: Unsure**

**Question**

I am really stuck here now to how to create a table design to record such information. Its just basic `Yes` as checked and `No` as not checked. But at the same time - If June was checked for that particular month - mark as checked.

Anybody has any clues where I can start creating a table to record such information?

Here is a fiddle link:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba8cab/2

Comment: You first need to know/store when the equipment was bought/installed, then you need the period of the maintenance, then you need to schedule a specific date the upcoming maintenance task and once it is completed - either schedule a new task or uninstall the equipment.

Comment: something like this you mean? `create table maintenance_schedule(
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
Maintenance_Equipment_ID int,
tasks_ID int,
check_interval int);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have something like these:

```
Table EQUIPMENT
+------------------+----------------+
| ID               | AUTO_INCREMENT |
+------------------+----------------+
| NAME             | VARCHAR        |
+------------------+----------------+
| SERIAL_NUMBER    | VARCHAR        |
+------------------+----------------+
| DATE_PURCHASED   | DATE           |
+------------------+----------------+
| DATE_INSTALLED   | DATE           |
+------------------+----------------+
| DATE_UNINSTALLED | DATE           |
+------------------+----------------+

Table TASKS
+------------------------+----------------+
| ID                     | AUTO_INCREMENT |
+------------------------+----------------+
| NAME                   | VARCHAR        |
+------------------------+----------------+
| anything else you need |  ......        |
+------------------------+----------------+

Table TASK_PLAN
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID                 | AUTO_INCREMENT                                             |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| EQUIPMENT_ID       | foreign key into table EQUIPMENT                           |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| TASK_ID            | foreign key into table TASKS                               |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| MAINTENANCE_PERIOD | INT - number of days between each maintenance of this type |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+

Table SCHEDULES
+--------------+----------------------------------+
| PLAN_ID      | foreign key into table TASK_PLAN |
+--------------+----------------------------------+
| PLANNED_DATE | DATE                             |
+--------------+----------------------------------+
| STAFF_ID     | foreign key into table EMPLOYEES |
+--------------+----------------------------------+
| RESULT       | BOOLEAN                          |
+--------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have something along them lines as your answer - glad I am on the same path as your thinking.